# Getting byte offset with MRJob

Tags: hadoop, streaming, mapreduce

According to "The Definitive Guide to Hadoop", the input format `TextInputFormat` gives key value pairs `(k, v) = (byte offset, line)`. However, in MRJob, the key in the mapper input is always `None`. It should be easy to get the byte offset as key, since that's what TextInputFormat does. How do I get this?

I know that you can use the environment variable 'map_input_start' and calculate byte offsets yourself, but this has caused problems and I would like to do it the much simpler way of just getting the offset as key.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't defining the map method in your mapper class with the following signature give you the byte offset as the key.

```
public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,OutputCollector<>,Reporter)
```

Comment: MRJob is a python library for using Hadoop streaming. I was hoping not to have to mess with Java code

Answer (score 0):

The TextInputFormat is a Java class ... I do not see how that would work in the streaming world.